# Gulp task does not create a folder and file in simple task

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, directory

Could someone tell me why Gulp does not create a folder for me ? I dont have any error, it just not works. In the same task I can see te output from `console.log` Here is my Gulpfile.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
watch = require('gulp-watch');


gulp.task('css', function(){
  console.log('blebleblebleblebelbelbelble');
   return gulp.src('./app/assets/styles/styles.css').pipe(gulp.dest('./app/temp/styles'));
});


gulp.task('watch', function(){
  watch('./app/styles/**/*.css',function(){
    gulp.start('css');
  });
});
```

Here is a link to the [GitHub project](https://github.com/kendyl93/travel-site) (I am learning Gulp and other things on it)

Result on the Command line:

```
$ gulp watch
[20:26:01] Working directory changed to ~\desktop\projekty\travel-site
[20:26:02] Using gulpfile ~\desktop\projekty\travel-site\gulpfile.js
[20:26:02] Starting 'watch'...
[20:26:02] Finished 'watch' after 12 ms
[20:26:09] Starting 'css'...
blebleblebleblebelbelbelble
[20:26:09] Finished 'css' after 17 ms
```

Here is my Project

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the file path is correct? I tried this myself and it created the temp and style folder with style.css inside as expected.

Comment: I have just added the image. Please check

Comment: It looks like you should have the following for gulp.src - gulp.src('./app/styles/styles.css')

Comment: Oh Lord ! How I couldn't noticed it... Gracias !

Comment: No problem glad to help :)